# How to insert a string before a matched string

Tags: shell, shell-script

How can I insert a string before a matched string. 
Suppose I want to insert a string a before "`if (PROTOCOL == "https://")`" string. Please tell me how can I do this??

or

How to search and replace a string like

```
function __construct($url='', $loc='')
{
```

to

```
function __construct($url='', $loc='') {
```

Please help if any one can know that.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` command is used to replace word / string syntax

The syntax is as follows:

```
sed -i 's/function __construct($url='', $loc='') {/function __construct($url='', $loc='') {/g' file_name
```